# Unity adding the host as a player when starting the server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

Currently im trying to make a lobby system for my game, the lobby system seems to have quite a few issues but im slowly working my way through them. I cannot however, find out a way to make the host automatically get added as a player in the game, when he starts a server. There will never be a situation where the host will only act as the server, so i need him to automatically get added to the game.

I have tried a bunch of different things with `ClientScene.AddPlayer()` But i cannot make this work.

Further, i cannot find any documentation on what functions the different buttons on the standard unity network lobby hud actually do, so i have a hard time replicating the behaviour.

Anyone has any good sources /ideas on the issue?

Comment: I've actually gone through the code for one of the NetworkLobbyManager projects Unity's released on the Asset Store, and then called the functions from code that are called when clicking the buttons. This resulted in some errors, so it's not yet clear what functions need to be called and in what order. If you want to try the same, you may reach a better result than I have.

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem, but check this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnServerInitialized.html Using this magic method do all you need to add a server to the game.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the given NetworkManager called StartHost(). Try this for starting the server.

See the Scripting API for [NetworkManager.StartHost()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StartHost.html) and all the methods from the [NetworkManager](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.html)

Comment: This is not what im asking. I do know how to start the server and add clients. The issue is that the standard GUI unity uses is WAY too small when i port it to a mobile device, and as such i am creating my own GUI.

I cannot however make the local client automatically spawn when he hosts the server, and as such he is never added to the game (remote clients are added successfully when they join the lobby)

Comment: So you are writing a custum NetworkManager? Or what are you exactly doing? Can you paste some code for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom UI and network manager to eliminate the Start Server GUI option which is by default provide by the Unity Networking GUI component. You can view this simple tutorial ([UI & Custom Net Manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w2kwGDZ6wM)) to understand it.